# How to combine product details and booking details in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm making a website for renting a car using PHP and MySQL .But I'm stuck, because I don't know how to combine car details and booking form details and show it in PHPMyAdmin when user submits the form.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Representation

You need to create relational representation in your MySQL database, like a table for cars, of the like of

**cars(id, ...)**

Where the **...** represents whatever details you intend to store.

## Storing a car

You need to create a PHP script that takes car details as input and stores cars as output. Since you already told us that you have a form, you will most likely use `$_POST` (an array with your named form elements for the form that you have submitted) as the input, but it is strongly recommended that you separate your functionality part from the definition of your input. So, you will most likely have a function/method (a standalone function or a method of a class) that will look something like this:

```
function storeCar($input) {
    //...
}
```

where `$input` is an associative array and you actually store the values. Of course, pay attention to [SQL injection](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/sql-injection-sqli/) and [XSS injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) as possibilities. These are possible vulnerabilities that infest the codes of most beginners. You can used [parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection and `htmlspecialchars` to protect against XSS injection.

Your code will end up executing an `insert into ...` type of command once you POST your form.

## Loading cars

You can execute `select * from cars` to see what your cars' details are (but it's better to list only the columns you are interested about) at any places that are connected to MySQL, including PHPMyAdmin. Or, in some UIs, such as PHPMyAdmin you can click on table names.

Comment: @NavyaMariamBabu happy to help! If this answer solved the issue for you, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.